# how to configure firefox to access the internet only via wireless network in win 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, firefox

My laptop is connected to two networks. One is a wired network and the other is wireless. My OS is Windows 7. How do I configure Firefox to only access the internet via the wireless network?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add new route for this case.

NIC 1 (Wifi) for Internet and NIC 2 for LAN.

Set a default route to go through NIC 1 and set LAN to NIC 2.

route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 <- depends on your LAN setup

Comment: can you explain more detail? FYI, I am still using the wired network for working. Usually I use IE for the wired network.

Comment: The idea is to ask Windows redirect your request. Internet goes to Wifi and local network goes to your wired. In order to achieve this, you need a static route. You must know the range of your local network IP address. [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757323(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: the wireless network is dhcp network.